# Is it known if there is any licence to be made for creating content using the D6 rules?

Tags: ogl, d6-system

As many of the books are now OGL and west end games no longer existing. Is there any licence for the d6 game system?

Or can one create content without having to licence anything?

Comment: You know that the books are OGL (aka, Open Game **License**), and you're asking if there's a license…?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I wasnt too sure if that was really the case with the ogl (the first book I looked at on drivethrough (fantasy book) didn't mention ogl at all and only a fan side mentioned it). Additionally the producer is gone and there was no info if anyone still had the licence itself and thus the possibility of revoking it (like it happened to D20). And as far as I see wizards is mentioned in this special version of the ogl oO

Comment: The OGL can't be revoked and d20 is still OGL. Once material is released under it, it's permanently released as OGL. (Wizards is mentioned in every copy of the OGL because the words of the license itself are their creation.)

Comment: Ah tnx. hmmmm just remembered about D20 the full details. Those who had published D20 already could decide D20 or 4th. For all others only 4th was available furthermore (always thought D20 was full OGL so that revoking was.....shocking).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thus I wasn't sure if the OGL could be revoked or has been revokedn again,...

Comment: That's not what happened. The OGL can't be revoked for anyone and never was. You can rest assured that the OGL can't and won't be revoked in the future.

Comment: ok interesting then I always interpreted it wrongly tnx.

Comment: If you want the full story and its breakdown, maybe make it into a question?

Comment: Already planing on that ;)....and done: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73563/the-d20-4th-edition-ogl-licence-switching-what-was-really-up-there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Whitesaber](http://games.whitesaber.com/west-end-games-open-d6.html):

> These West End Game books were released under the Open Game License and have been released by the publisher, Purgatory Publishing, as freely available.

The books in question cover the generic d6 system so, assuming it is accurate, you can produce d6 content under the OGL.

Comment: Does that open game licence then mean that all rules in these books can be used and taken to provide any sort of content (books, cmoputer games,...) witout having to take on a licence from anyone,... (or informing anyone that one does create the content)?

Comment: I suggest you read the OGL (included in each of the books) which lays out all the restrictions you have to operate under.

Comment: as I didn't see it under the page there....is there any mention if tis a specific OGL that is used? (as far as I'm aware OGL is like open source that there are a few subversions out there that are all called by the same general group name)

Comment: I picked a book at random (D6 Adventure) and it was on the last page.

Comment: tnx I had only looked on the fantasy book and there the ogl page wasnt in (at least at the version from drivethroughrpg)